# how do get php to open a page?

Tags: php, http, curl

I am attempting to open a specified page automatically upon loading a PHP page, but not by means of redirecting, is file_get_contents suitable for this? Also I have tried curl with the following, however  I do not see any responses:

```
curl_setopt($ch=curl_init(), CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: same result, do not see anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cURL is perfect for that situation. If you just want to to display the page, you don't need to  set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` as the default behaviour is to display the result.

Check for errors:

```
if ($response === false) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
```

Comment: well i don't even need to display the page all i need to do is invoke the URL

Comment: So your code should work. You question was: *however I do not see any responses* and you just told me you don't need the response. I'm confused.

Comment: well i want to confirm i am getting a ping at least and by using curl for some reason i do not see any responses at all.

Comment: that does not do anything either, i think this line makes it hang $ch=curl_init();

Comment: What does `var_dump($response)` says?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to get the contents of the page, `file_get_contents` will do.

Comment: i just want to invoke the URL, i do not even care about the contents returned, although a return code would be nice

Comment: well, `file_get_contents` will return `false` if it fails, but you won't get any information about why it failed (404, 403, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Using `file_get_contents` would do the trick but you need to enable allow_url_fopen.

You can also use CURL but your code is not working becasue you are missing `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`

Full Script

```
curl_setopt($ch=curl_init(), CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
echo curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: i have tried this and still do not see any response from the server end

Comment: You must be having errors put this on top of your page `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: nothing happens, if i get rid of the curl stuff i can see "hello world" display (as expected)

Answer (score 1):

> > is file_get_contents suitable for this?

Yes, if your server allow you to use this function it is suitable

```
 <?php
    echo "<h2>Here we go</h2>";
    $content = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
    echo $content;
 ?>
```

Also you are able to modify the $content